# Exporting Names of Inputs and Outputs of a Simulink Model to a Excel File

Tags: excel, matlab, import, export-to-excel, simulink

How Can I Export Names of All Inputs and Outputs of a Simulink Model to a Excel File?

I have tried to code a script file but it is nothing more than scratch. I am expecting to import all the inputs and outputs of my Simulink model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is fairly simple

```
model_name = 'port_test';

mdl = load_system(model_name);

inputs = find_system(mdl,'BlockType','Inport');
input_names = arrayfun(@(x) get_param(x,'Name'), inputs,'UniformOutput',false);

outputs = find_system(mdl,'BlockType','Outport');
output_names = arrayfun(@(x) get_param(x,'Name'), inputs,'UniformOutput',false);
```

- `load_system` opens the system of interest and returns the model
  handle
- `find_system` is a powerful function (backwards compatible
  with many versions of MATLAB which will search through a model for
  blocks/items that match. It will return an array of handles for each
  object found
- `arrayfun` performs a function on an array of items.
- `get_param` is used to get the name of each of the items found by
  `find_system`

Two cell arrays (input_names and output_names) will be created and will contain a list of all the inputs and output blocks in the top level of the model specified by model_name.

For writing out to a spreadsheet, I'd suggest using the power of the [writetable](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/writetable.html) function.

Could be something as simple as this

```
input_table = table(input_names);
writetable(input_table,[model_name '.xlsx'],'Sheet','Inputs');

output_table = table(input_names);
writetable(output_table,[model_name '.xlsx'],'Sheet','Outputs','WriteMode','append');
```